# Error while trying to repeat a script multiple times in a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to execute this code 500 times and save it as an array, x.

```
    u=rand();

    m=1;
    while(u>=cum_prob(m))%
        m=m+1;
    end

    x=(bin_edges(m-1)-bin_edges(m-2))/(cum_prob(m-1)-cum_prob(m-2))*(u-((((bin_edges(m-1)*cum_prob(m-2))-((bin_edges(m-2)*cum_prob(m-1))))/(bin_edges(m-1)-bin_edges(m-2)))));
```

That works when I run it. Now i need to do this 500 times and stores the results in an array, x. The code that I have written to do so is shown below, however I am getting the error "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values." at the line that starts with  x(a)=.....

```
x=zeros(1,500);
for a=1:500
    u=rand();

    m=1;
    while(u>=cum_prob(m))%
        m=m+1;
    end

    x(a)=(bin_edges(m-1)-bin_edges(m-2))/(cum_prob(m-1)-cum_prob(m-2))*(u-((((bin_edges(m-1)*cum_prob(m-2))-((bin_edges(m-2)*cum_prob(m-1))))/(bin_edges(m-1)-bin_edges(m-2)))));

end
```

If anyone could please point me in the right direction, that would be great! Thankyou

Comment: I'm going by heart, not having Matlab working on this machine, but: what happens if you assign x(1,a) instead of x(a)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `u<cum_prob(m)` then `m = 1`. In the `x(a)` line you have `bin_edges(m-1)`, `bin_edges(m-2)`, `cum_prob(m-2)` and `cum_prob(m-2)`. I don't know what `bin_edges` is, but I'm assuming that at least `cum_prob` is a vector, thus `m-2` will cause an error.